i want to connected my table screen to firestore with streambuilder
my signin page
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/Home_screen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/Registration_screen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/TableScreen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Widgets/My_button.dart';

class Signin extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = 'Signin';
  const Signin({super.key});

  @override
  State<Signin> createState() => _SigninState();
}

class _SigninState extends State<Signin> {
  var emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var compoundcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var FullNamecontroler = TextEditingController();
  var IDcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var logincontroller = TextEditingController();
  var logoutcontroller = TextEditingController();

  // Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
  //   'fullname':fullname
  //   // Add other user data fields as needed
  // };
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Image.asset('images/pro85guard.png'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: emailcontroller,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Your Email',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: passwordcontroller,
                    obscureText: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Your Password',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      if (emailcontroller.text == "") {
                        AwesomeDialog(
                          context: context,
                          dialogType: DialogType.error,
                          animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                          title: 'Error',
                          desc: 'يرجى كتابه البريد الالكترونى',
                        ).show();
                        return;
                      }
                      try {
                        await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(
                            email: emailcontroller.text);
                        AwesomeDialog(
                          context: context,
                          dialogType: DialogType.success,
                          animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                          title: 'Info',
                          desc:
                              'يرجى الذهاب الى بريدك الالكترونى وتغير كلمه السر',
                        ).show();
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                      AwesomeDialog(
                        context: context,
                        dialogType: DialogType.error,
                        animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                        title: 'Error',
                        desc: 'يرجى التاكد من بريدك الالكترونى ر',
                      ).show();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 20),
                      child: const Text(
                        "Forgot Password?",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Mybutton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      title: 'SignIn',
                      onpressed: () async {
                        try {
                          final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: emailcontroller.text,
                                  password: passwordcontroller.text);

                          if (credential.user!.emailVerified) {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(
                              context,
                              Tablescreen.screenroute,
                              arguments: {
                                'email': emailcontroller.text,
                                'FullName': FullNamecontroler.text,
                                'login': logincontroller.text,
                                'ID': IDcontroller.text,
                                'compound': compoundcontroller.text,
                              },
                            );
                            Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context, Homescreen.screenroute);
                          } else {
                            FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!
                                .sendEmailVerification();
                            AwesomeDialog(
                              context: context,
                              dialogType: DialogType.error,
                              animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                              title: 'Error',
                              desc: 'يرجى التحقق من البريد الالكترونى',
                            ).show();
                          }
                        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                          if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                            print('No user found for that email.');
                          } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                            print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
                          }
                        }
                      }),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("Don't have an a account?"),
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(
                                  context, Registrationscreen.screenroute);
                            },
                            child: Text('SignUp'),
                          ))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}


my signup page
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/Home_screen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Widgets/My_button.dart';

class Registrationscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = 'Registrationscreen';
  const Registrationscreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<Registrationscreen> createState() => _RegistrationscreenState();
}

class _RegistrationscreenState extends State<Registrationscreen> {
  var emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var idcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var fullnamecontroller = TextEditingController();
  var compoundcontroller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Image.asset('images/pro85guard.png'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: fullnamecontroller,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Your Full Name',
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: idcontroller,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Your ID',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.numbers),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: emailcontroller,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Your Email',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: passwordcontroller,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Your Password',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: compoundcontroller,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Your compound location',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_city),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Mybutton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    title: 'Register',
                    onpressed: () async {
                      try {
                        final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: emailcontroller.text,
                          password: passwordcontroller.text,
                        );
                        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!
                            .sendEmailVerification();

                        // Add user data to Firestore
                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('signup')
                            .doc(emailcontroller.text)
                            .set({
                          'FullName': fullnamecontroller.text,
                          'ID': idcontroller.text,
                          'email': emailcontroller.text,
                          'Compound': compoundcontroller.text,
                          // Add more fields as needed
                        });

                        // Add user information to a subcollection named 'signupemail'
                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('signup')
                            .doc(emailcontroller.text)
                            .collection('signupemail')
                            .doc()
                            .set({
                          'fullName': fullnamecontroller.text,
                          'id': idcontroller.text,
                          'email': emailcontroller.text,
                          'password': passwordcontroller.text,
                          // Add more fields as needed
                        });

                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Homescreen.screenroute);
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                          print('The password provided is too weak.');
                        } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
                          print('The account already exists for that email.');
                        }
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}


I want when i make signup my data in uploaded to my table and every uploaded data                               table will updated  I want when i make signup my data in uploaded to my table and every uploaded data                               table will updated
my tablescreen code
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Tablescreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = 'Tablescreen';
  const Tablescreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Tablescreen> createState() => _TablescreenState();
}

class _TablescreenState extends State<Tablescreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: "Table",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Select Table",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Sort Table",
            ),
          ],
        ),
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            " Daily Reports",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                // Loading indicator while waiting for data
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                // Error message if stream encounters an error
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                // If snapshot has no data or collection is empty
                return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
              } else {
                // Data is available, build the table
                final data = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return DataTable(
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text("FullName"),
                        numeric: false,
                        tooltip: "to display fullname of the name"),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text("Login"),
                        numeric: false,
                        tooltip: "to display Login of the name"),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text("ID"),
                        numeric: false,
                        tooltip: "to display ID of the name"),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text("Compound"),
                        numeric: false,
                        tooltip: "to display Compound of the name"),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text("Logout"),
                        numeric: false,
                        tooltip: "to display Signup of the name"),
                  ],
                  rows: data.map<DataRow>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    final Map<String, dynamic> userData =
                        document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(Text(userData['FullName'].toString())),
                        DataCell(Text(userData['login'].toString())),
                        DataCell(Text(userData['ID'].toString())),
                        DataCell(Text(userData['compound'].toString())),
                        DataCell(Text(userData['Logout'].toString())),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I want when i make signup my data in uploaded to my table and every uploaded data table will updated and I want to solve when run code table still empty

you're signup data is stored in "signup" collection and in StreamBuilder you're fetching data from "signing" collection.
